# How to use back slashes Python

Tags: python

How do I use slashes in Python strings? To be more clear, I need to use a backward slash with a Python string. I know that `\` is considered a keyword in Python for the escape character. My problem is, I am trying to write a string that uses `\` inside of a file path name but when I try to write the full path name inside of the string, the back slash keeps me from using the string because of this error: `SyntaxError: EOL` while scanning string literal. I have been around Python just long enough to know this is a syntax error dealing with a string that doesn't have a `'` at the end of it but even after I add one, I still get the same error. Does anyone know how I can use it?

I have also tried adding random data to the string and replacing it with the back slash but that gives the same error. My code requires the system drive name ( `C:` ) to be a string called `SYSTEM_DRIVE` and then a separate string called `USERNAME`. I am using `getpass.getuser()` to grab the username of the current running user and store the output in `USERNAME`. Afterwards I am combining the `SYSTEM_DRIVE` with `USERNAME` and adding the directory and file name of the needed document to one final string and that string be used for the needed operations.

Note: This is written in Python 2.7 ( Yes, I know Python 2.7 is about to expire but it's the Python version i started with and I am trying to finish this project in it before I migrate to 3. I am working on learning C++ before I switch over).

Code:

```
import os, getpass
SYSTEM_DRIVE = "C:\"
USERNAME = getpass.getuser() + '\'
FILE_PATH = SYSTEM_DRIVE + USERNAME + 'Example\TEXT_FILE.txt'
if os.path.isfile(FILE_PATH):
   print (' [*] File is present on the system [*] ')
else:
   print (' [*] No file was found [*] ')
```

This example does not feature my full path. I just used Example and TEST_FILE as a holder.
Edit: Sorry everyone for the confusion someone changed my question title or i must have made something not clear.

Comment: `"C:\\" `or `r"C:\"`

Comment: `"C:/"` will work just fine. We can use and even mix Windows and Linux path dividers

Comment: the term you are looking for is escape sequence. see https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: I have accepted another answer but thank you all for your input i have fixed my problem and have learned a few new tricks and i did not know you could mix them thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix here. Using a `\` with another one cause it to escape the previous one so if the backslash is your challenge then use `\\` this will escape the  backslash and output it as a normal string so `"C:\\path\\to\\file"`. Another option would be to make it a raw string by adding an r in front of it so something like 
`r"C:\path\to\html.text"` and this should also output a string for you and not escape any characters

Comment: This solved my problem i have corrected my code and accepted your answer and yeah i saw that online and in the other great responses to this question however it didn't seem to work maybe i'm doing something wrong? Either way i am going to mess around with raw strings and figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Stop using '\' character -- it's not portable and might not work on a different platform. Use `os.path.join()` instead, or `os.path.sep`, if you really need that:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.sep
'/'
>>> os.path.join( 'folder', 'file.txt')
'folder/file.txt'
>>>
```

JFYI, I'm on Linux. Windows machine will give you a different output.

Comment: I'm writing this for a Windows machine but i respect the Linux lovers i'm one myself just trying to write this project for Windows so i can get a grasp on another platform besides Linux based

Comment: @Sue `os.path.sep` will give you the local path separator. on a windows machine you'll get `\` as expected, and your code will be more portable

Comment: @njzk2 On SO you should escape back slashes in comments: `\\` ;)